# How can I use oculus Mobile SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, sdk, oculus, gear-vr

I have an application which is supported by Google Cardboard and runs great on Gear Vr. Now instead of Cardboard I would like it to be supported by the oculus Mobile SDK but I have trouble integrating the SDK. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried and how do you know it works under GearVR? (Are you flipping the USB plug up out of the way?)

Comment: @Robert I tested it on Gear VR...  I basiclly want to know if it is possible to work with the oculus Mobile Sdk in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's difficult know exactly what you have implemented but here are a couple of snippets from [a tutorial on building a dual Cardboard-GearVR app](http://ralphbarbagallo.com/2015/05/26/how-to-support-gear-vr-and-google-cardboard-in-one-unity3d-project/) that may or may not help, depending on your project:

1. Google Cardboard supports Unity 4 and Unity 5. Although Oculus’ mobile SDK will technically work on Unity 5, you can’t ship with it because bugs in the current version of Unity 5 cause memory leaks and other issues on the Gear VR hardware.
2. You can install the Cardboard and Gear VR SDKs in a single Unity project with almost no problems. The only conflict is they both overwrite the Android manifest in the plugin folder.

There is some more information in the link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my application already has Cardboard + I don´t want to work with unity.